# How to display latest booking date result

Tags: php, date

How do I to display the latest booking result where `$date > strtotime("now")`, as I can only display the booking records.

This is my PHP code

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT bookingid, date, slot, location FROM booking WHERE username=?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $username); 

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($bookingid, $date, $slot, $location);

        echo"<table>";
        echo"<b>Latest Bookings</b>";
        echo "<tr><th><b>Date</b></th>
        <th><b>Slot</b></th>
        <th><b>Location</b></th>
        <th><b>Actions</b></th>";

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                if( $date > strtotime("now")) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><p>$date";
                echo "<td><p>$slot</td>";
                echo "<td><p>$location</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        else{
            echo"<table>";
            echo"<b>Booking History</b>";
            echo "<tr><th><b>Date</b></th>
            <th><b>Slot</b></th>
            <th><b>Location</b></th>";
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td><p>$date";
                echo "<td><p>$slot</td>";
                echo "<td><p>$location</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: <code>$date</code> is which formate, like 2017-01-15 13:05:59, 1484471357...

Comment: it is in 2017-1-15

Comment: is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$date > strtotime("now")` to this `strtotime($date) > strtotime("now")`, I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks, however i would like to know if i can use a while ($stmt->fetch()) {} inside a while ($stmt->fetch()) {} ? cause it doesnt display all of my booking history